# xmln:tns and targetNamespace

Tags: xsd, xml-namespaces

I am seeing some XSD schema documents that declare both a `targetNamespace` and an `xmlns:tns` attribute in their top `schema` element. E.g. the following one taken [from here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/reusing-generated-jaxb-classes.html). They also seem to have the same string value. I understand the role of `targetNamespace` but what does `xmlns:tns` do on top of that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Product"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Product"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
...
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It lets you refer to the namespace later in the schema.  For example, if you declare a named type and then want to also declare an element of that type

```
<complexType name="someType">
  <!-- ... -->
</complexType>

<element name="someElement" type="tns:someType" />
```

Simply saying `type="someType"` wouldn't work because that would be referring to the (non-existent) `someType` in the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace (the `xmlns="..."` of the schema file) rather than the one in the `http://www.example.org/Product` namespace.

Comment: OK, so 'tns' in this sense is like any other prefix bound to a namespace, it bears no special significance whatsoever, just like all other prefixes, right?

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus indeed, you could use any prefix you like.  The prefix `tns` is common in this context as a mnemonic for "target name space" but you could just as well use `product`, `ns0`, or whatever.

Comment: If you have "xmlns:tns" do you need "targetNamespace"? I'm trying to work with an XSD from another group and it has "xmlns:tns" but not "targetNamespace".

Comment: @MikeStoddart they generally appear together, simply because it's when you have a schema with a `targetNamespace` that you then need a prefix like `tns:` to be able to refer to types and elements declared in the schema from elsewhere.  If the schema has no `targetNamespace` then its types aren't in a namespace so the cross-references don't need a prefix.  It may simply be that the `xmlns:tns` is leftover from an earlier edit, and none of the references in the schema actually use `tns:anything`