# Java XML Create Fragment/Elements Without Namespace

Tags: java, xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to construct an XML document using `org.w3c.dom.Document` to create some XML for another existing tool. The problem I am having is that the tool seems to have the XML namespaces in a strange way. How can I replicate this using the Java API's?

```
<ns1:myroot xmlns:ns1="http://foo.com/ns1/">
  <ns2:bar xmlns:ns2="http://foo.com/xml/bar/">
    <ns2:bar_thing>abc</ns2:bar_thing>
  </ns2:bar>
  <ns3:data xmlns:ns3="http://foo.com/xml/special-ns">
    <!--These are not namespaced for some reason. If I use the ns3 prefix, or
      use a default xmls="...", the tool fails to load the document, saying the
      elements have invalid values.
      -->
      <a>Element without namespace</a>
      <b>
        <bi>1</bi>
        <bii>2</bii>
      </b>
  </ns3:data>
</ns1:myroot>
```

I can build most of the document easily with `createElementNS` and `setAttributeNS`. However I can't get the `ns3:data` contents to be correct.

Trying to use the non-namespace `createElement` still left an `xmlns="http://foo.com/xml/special-ns">` on my `a` and `b` elements, as did using `createElementNS` with an empty namespace, and obviously a non-empty namespace puts them in a namespace.

The schema for `http://foo.com/xml/special-ns` has a bunch of declarations like these below, not sure what the `tns` thing is about, but otherwise does not seem special (although I am not 100% sure the tool actually does anything with the XSD and I don't have access to the source).

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://foo.com/xml/special-ns">
  <!--Bunch of xs:element such as this-->
  <xs:element name="data" type="tns:data" />

  <!--types declared after-->
  <xs:complexType name="data">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="a" type="tns:aDataObj" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="b" type="tns:bDataObj" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="aDataObj">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="bDataObj">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="bi" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="bii" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Does the document declare a default namespace via `xmlns="http://something"` ?

Comment: No, it needs to be just like in the snippet with only namespace names / attribute locations changing, if those elements are in a namespace in anyway, including default namespace on any parent element, the tool wont process it.

Comment: do you have the schema definition for `<ns3:data>` ?

Comment: Added a representative example, all the elements it defines follow the same naming/type pattern, just 1000's more and somewhat more complex.

Comment: According to that schema, the data element should have namespace `http://foo.com/xml/special-ns` but in your example it has namespace prefix ns3 - is ns3 mapped to the special-ns URL?

Comment: Also, the a and b child elements are in the namespace mapped to tns, but that prefix isn't associated to an actual namespace (in your schema snippet).  tns is not special but people usually let it to refer to the target namespace see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295588/xmlntns-and-targetnamespace)

Comment: oh sorry, that attribute was wrong, yes it is ns3. And no, the tns prefix is not associated to an actual namespace in the real xsd file I pulled off the referenced server.

Comment: Even if the server code does use that xsd in its processing (which I don't think it does), I wouldn't be able to change it on the live server, so still need some solution in the XML side to get a dom that does the "right thing" for this remote server. Do I somehow declare the "tns" prefix in my XML so that the server might recognise them if Java is forcing me to have some namespace/prefix for them?

Comment: Have you tried pulling in the schema into an editor that can validate it?  I think the reason a and b can't have a namespace is because tns isn't defined - the schema is not valid. You can try to define it in the document prior to reading the schema. Are you using lax validation?

Comment: The code, where is the code? How shall we find the problem if you don't show the code which creates the XML?